# Подскажите jquery плагин карусели как у гугла?

Tags: jquery, карусель, carousel

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин карусели [как у гугла](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%8B%202019&safe=off&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR9smUtejfAhWFpIsKHahUD_EQ_AUICSgA&biw=1920&bih=1324&dpr=1.5)

Отличительные особенности, что она перетягивается курсором и перемещается на любую длину(не строго по значению)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагин [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

Параметр `freeScroll: true` позволяет скроллить без выравнивания элементов.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bNLGNZ)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, добрый человек!